# Using Font-awesome icons dynamically does not work with the SVG & JS implementation

Tags: javascript, ajax, svg, font-awesome

So I'm using font-awesome's new JS&SVG implementation for their v5 icons. The implementation works fine, for icons (e.g. `<i class='fas fa-home'></i>`) that are present in the DOM at page load and the `<i>` tag is replaced with an `<svg>` tag.

Problem occurs when I load in some HTML server-side and insert it into the DOM, the `<i>` tags does not converted and thus no icon is displayed. I cannot find any method that I can use in my JS (like after the content is added to the DOM) to "reinstance" the JS implementation to load the SVG icons in place.

Has anyone come by this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using it like this and working well even on "after-loaded" html parts.

My `fontawesome.js` is looking like this:

```
import { library, dom, config } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';

config.autoReplaceSvg = true;
config.observeMutations = true; // <- this is what you need the most

import { faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons/faUser';
import { faFacebook } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faFacebook';

library.add(faUser, faFacebook);

// And this is important too
// Replace any existing <i> tags with <svg> and set up a MutationObserver to
// continue doing this as the DOM changes.
dom.watch();
```

...and then I require this `fontawesome.js` in my `vendors.js`.

The reason why it is not working for you is mentioned in the documentation:

> **Different default configs**
>   DOM watching is on by default when Font
>   Awesome is loaded from `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free` or
>   `@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro` but it's disabled for the
>   `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core`.

Here are some useful links on the [configuration](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/setup/configuration), [watching the dom](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/with-the-api/methods/dom-watch) and [svg-javascript-core](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/svg-javascript-core)